# CATransform3D Animation for Rotation+Scaling not Smooth

Tags: ios, core-animation, catransform3d

I'm trying to add this 3D animation but it's not animating it properly. There is a jerk during the animation.

```
    var currentTransform = CATransform3DIdentity
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

        currentTransform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.5, 0.5, 1)
        currentTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -800
        currentTransform = CATransform3DRotate(currentTransform, CGFloat(M_PI) * 50.0/180.0, 0, 1, 0)



        self.containerView.layer.transform = currentTransform


    })
```

What can be the problem and how to solve it?

**UPDATE (Answer):**

This piece of code works fine. The only problem was, the containerView was an immediate subView of my main view and this was causing the jerk. 
The solution to this is, I added another view to my main view and made the containerView a subview of the newly added view. 
Though I'm not sure why this happened. I think, the transformation I was doing on my containerView, also affected the layer of the main view through transformation.

Comment: What is `currentTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -800` intended for?

Comment: To give a 3D effect of the rotating view. Something like opening the door effect.